# How do you specify additional trusted files with the Jenkins Github Branch Source plugin?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I've created a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline with the GitHub Branch Source plugin. The `Jenkinsfile` essentially just calls a Cake Build script (`build.ps1`, `build.cake`) that contains all the build/deploy logic. This allows me to move to another CI service easily.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to add my Cake Build scripts as a `trusted file` so that PR's from forks will pull the files from the source repo instead. The `Trust` setting of the `Discover pull requests from forks` behavior seems to indicate that there can be other `trusted files` besides `Jenkinsfile`:

> **Nobody**
>
> Pull requests from forks will all be treated as untrusted. This means that where Jenkins requires **a trusted file (e.g. Jenkinsfile)** the contents of that file will be retrieved from the target branch on the origin repository and not from the pull request branch on the fork repository.

However, I cannot seem to find any documentation on adding other `trusted files`. The primary reason for this is to prevent a PR from a fork from accessing `credentials` from the Cake script. They wouldn't be able to change `Jenkinsfile`, but they could still change the Cake script to expose the credentials.

Is it actually possible to add other `trusted files`?

Comment: I also have the same problems. Have you managed to figured this out?

Comment: @UltimaWeapon Unfortunately, I have not. I ended up switching over to Azure Pipelines instead.

Comment: I see. Thanks for information.

Answer (score 0):

<del>It seems like Jenkins does not support this. My solution is checking out the untrusted files manually from the base version instead. First getting the commit 's hash of the base version with:</del>

```
def commit = sh(
    script: 'git rev-parse HEAD',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()

def base = sh(
    script: "git rev-list --parents -n 1 ${commit}",
    returnStdout: true
).trim().split('\\s+')[2]
```

<del>`git rev-list --parents -n 1 ${commit}` will return the hash of current commit, which is a merge commit that was created by Jenkins; the latest commit of the PR and the latest commit of the target branch, separated by a space (e.g. `05e9322574ea03003f87dcbb44f172e6fa62581f b3f6ef892af9c645f490106757d7d05df3a26060 069ffd55ae36414a51b4de166aef86966f9447a8`). Hence, we grab the hash of the latest commit of the target branch by `trim().split('\\s+')[2]`.</del>

<del>Now we can do `sh "git checkout ${base} FILE"` on any file that we don't trust from the PR.</del>

This does not works if the PR is already merged with the latest version of target branch. So what I did is something like this:

```
// revert untrusted files to the base version and backup it before we execute any untrusted code so the attacker
// don't have a chance to put a malicious content
def latest = sh(script: 'git rev-parse HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()

sh "git checkout origin/${env.CHANGE_TARGET}"

def baseCompose = readFile('docker-compose.yml')

// switch back to latest commit
sh "git checkout ${latest}"
sh 'git clean -d -f -f -q -x'
```